# Logarithm as a limit of sums

Tags: analysis, logarithms

Trying to understand a paper which makes use of the following "fact" about logarithms. Can someone please explain why it is so?

Let $\phi(x) = \sum_{x/a \leq n\leq x/b} 1/n$. Then $\lim_{x\to \infty}\phi(x) = \log(a/b)$. In other words,
$$\log(a/b) = \lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{x/a \leq n\leq x/b}\frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Do you know/can you show that $$\sum_{n \leqslant y} \frac{1}{n} = \log y + \gamma + O\biggl(\frac{1}{y}\biggr)\,?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i-\ln n\right)=\gamma$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{x/a\le n\le x/b}\frac 1n=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor x/b\rfloor}\frac1i-\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil x/a\rceil}\frac1i\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\ln\lfloor x/b\rfloor+\gamma-\ln\lceil x/a\rceil-\gamma)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\frac{\lfloor x/b\rfloor}{\lceil x/a\rceil}=\ln\frac ab$$

Comment: ah in the sum after the first equality, do you mean to switch b and a? other than that, thanks heaps!

Comment: @abe.nong it must have been a typo or slip-up of yours.

Comment: it definitely was my mistake. thanks!